# Servlets, How to make server available by the name in annotation?

Tags: servlets

I'm only starting to learn Servlets.
I have a simple template code below.

I thought that after writing annotation "@WebServlet("/hello-servlet")" my page will be available by the URL "http://localhost:8080/hello-servlet".
The problem is that it is not available by that adress only by "http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/".
I do know that the problem is connected with Tomcat configurations. In settings it is said that url is "http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded". And deployment is "war exploded".
How can I make the server available by the name in annotation?

```
@WebServlet("/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer - you just need to delete application context from deployment